# Compiling error on have 2 next variables

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to run code that will copy the text "ready" or "cancel" in column L, based on if there is a value in Column S or T respectively in the specif row.

I keep getting the error Compile error: Invalid Next control variable reference.

My code is as follows,

```
    Dim TimeToRun

Sub auto_open()
    Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver
End Sub


Sub ScheduleCopyPriceOver()
    TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CopyPriceOver"
End Sub

Sub CopyPriceOver()
Dim lRow    As Long
Dim ws      As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False



    For SRow = 1 To 5000
    For TRow = 1 To 5000
    If ws.Cells(SRow, 19) = SRow Then
        ws.Cells(SRow, 12).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ready"

     ElseIf ws.Cells(TRow, 20) = TRow Then
            ws.Cells(TRow, 12).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Cancel"

        Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver

    End If
    Next SRow
    Next TRow


End Sub

Sub auto_close()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CopyPriceOver", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: Indenting the code isn't only useful aesthetically, it makes code more readable and you might have spotted that your Next statements are the wrong way round.

Comment: Next TRow should come before Next SRow. TRow is the inner loop which must be closed before the outer loop.

Comment: you can omit the variable after `Next` keyword and have the compiler infer the right one

Comment: In fact you don't even need two loops.

Comment: How do I do it with just one loop? I tried using the code below from the 2 comments and my excel crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what Variatus meant...
Also it's not necessary to select a cell as per your code as selecting cells inside a loop will make your code slow.

```
Sub CopyPriceOver()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For SRow = 1 To 5000
        For TRow = 1 To 5000
            If ws.Cells(SRow, 19) = SRow Then
                ws.Cells(SRow, 12).Select
                ws.Cells(SRow, 12).Value = "ready"
            ElseIf ws.Cells(TRow, 20) = TRow Then
                ws.Cells(TRow, 12).Select
                ws.Cells(TRow, 12).Value = "Cancel"
                Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver
            End If
        Next TRow
    Next SRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your data looks like to be able to check the validity of your `IF` and `ELSEIF` statements, nor can we tell if running a 5,000 piece loop 5,000 times is warranted.... but tidying up your loop to the following will prevent the compilation error:

```
For SRow = 1 To 5000
    For TRow = 1 To 5000
        If ws.Cells(SRow, 19) = SRow Then
            ws.Cells(SRow, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "ready"
        ElseIf ws.Cells(TRow, 20) = TRow Then
            ws.Cells(TRow, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "Cancel"
            Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver
        End If
    Next TRow
Next SRow
```

(Note: I've removed the unnecessary cell selection also)

Answer (score 0):

Don't see why you can't do it like this

```
Sub CopyPriceOver()

Dim sRow    As Long
Dim ws      As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For sRow = 1 To 5000
    If ws.Cells(sRow, 19) = sRow Then
        ws.Cells(sRow, 12).Value = "Ready"
    ElseIf ws.Cells(sRow, 20) = sRow Then
        ws.Cells(sRow, 12).Value = "Cancel"
        Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver
    End If
Next sRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```